# How to provide a string value inside a parameter field value in karate?

Tags: javascript, karate

I have a requirement where I need to put the dynamic value from DB inside my parameter field. To get the dynamic value, I am using java helper.

```
* def randomSymbol = helper.listOfSymbols()
```

This return me symbol as "Test1, Test2".

Now I need to use this symbol in my API request parameter, like this:

```
And param filter = "(Symbol IN (randomSymbol))"
```

Can someone please point me, how can I insert this random symbol value inside my parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Everything is normal JavaScript:

```
And param filter = "(Symbol IN (" + randomSymbol + "))"
```